# SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: glassfish

When i try to run my `index.jsp` page which calls `WebClient.jsp` page, where i define my `InitialContext()` method, and implement my Bean in  class  `AccountBean.java` shows ..

> SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException........

I use Glassfish v3, jdk1.6, eclipse Helios.

Comment: Yes, give program details.  No answer is possible otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean by "If u want i will give my program details"? How can anyone help you with this minimal info?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give too specific an answer, but my recommendation for this issue is to make sure that every object you are trying to use is guaranteed to be pointing to an instance of the object.